# Why can I not call a method from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom class (Packages) that is of form NSObject. I have many instances of this object. In initializing each of these instances, I pass self from my UIViewController names ViewController.

In the code for these packages, I would like to call a method from ViewController.

```
-(void)toThisView:(UIView *)someView
{
    [imagesToRender addObject:someView];
    [self.mainImageView addSubview:someView];
}
```

and in Packages.m

I have

```
- (UIView *)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [view2 toThisView:sender.view]; // Error No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'toThisView:'
}
```

where view2 is `UIViewController *view2` and its being set as `view2 = object` via the init method of this classes

`- (id)initWithPath:(NSString *)path andObject:(NSObject *)object`

Why am I getting this error:

`No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'toThisView:'`

Comment: CustomClass *view2 = ...

Comment: YouCustomTomClassName instead of UIViewController *view2 or you can use perform selector method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `view2` is your custom type object then you can simply do this :

`[(YourCustomClass *)view2 toThisView:sender.view];`

import `YourCustomClass.` in viewController.

Comment: You are right, it needs to be casted as YourCustomClass. But I also had an issue and never imported the header file for YourCustomClass

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a class named `ViewController` which is a subclass of `UIViewController`.

It also sounds like you have an instance variable named `view2` which you declared like this:

```
@implementation Packages {
    UIViewController *view2;
}
```

or possibly like this:

```
@interface Packages : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *view2;
```

You need to declare `view2` to be a `ViewController`, not a `UIViewController`.  In other words, declare it like this:

```
@implementation Packages {
    ViewController *view2;
}
```

or like this:

```
@interface Packages : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *view2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add

```
-(void)toThisView:(UIView *)someView
```

To your viewController.h file, otherwise it won't be visible from any other class.

Answer (score 0):

1st import your custom class in viewController.
create an object of the class.

Call method simply like this.

```
 [object toThisView:YourPrameter];
```

Before calling also declare this method in your class .h file like this

```
-(void)toThisView:(UIView *)someView;
```